# How do I make check-boxes respond to a select all function after I manually checked and unchecked them?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom

I managed to select all check-boxes by getting the input elements via class name and add or remove their "checked" attribute. However, I've discovered that if I checked and unchecked any of the check-boxes, they are no longer affected when I try to select all of them. For example, in the image below, I checked and unchecked the first 3 check-boxes.

[image: UI example showing checkboxes not all being checked or unchecked.]

Things I have did:
1. Inspecting the elements - don't see any issues because the checkbox elements' attributes still update despite not showing any changes on the page.
2. Console - no errors reported here.

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" v-model="checked"></th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Course Title</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="course in courses" :key="course.id">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="inputs"></td>
        <td>{{course.id}}</td>
        <td>{{course.title}}</td>
        <td>{{course.price}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

```
export default {
  name: 'CourseTable',
  data () {
    return {
      courses: udemy.results,
      checked: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    check (arr) {
      for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        arr[i].setAttribute("checked", "")
      }
    },
    uncheck (arr) {
      for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        arr[i].removeAttribute("checked")
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    checked: function () {
      var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("inputs")
      if(this.checked){
        this.check(inputs)
      }else{
        this.uncheck(inputs)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this line `arr[i].setAttribute("checked", "")` to  `arr[i].checked = true`

and `arr[i].removeAttribute("checked")` to `arr[i].checked = false`

You can actually delete check and uncheck methods as well as the watch method. Then change your input checked value. Like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      checked: false,
      courses: [{
          id: "362328",
          title: "AWS",
          price: "179.99"
        },
        {
          id: "625204",
          title: "The web",
          price: "179.99"
        }, {
          id: "567828",
          title: "Complete",
          price: "179.99"
        }, {
          id: "756150",
          title: "Angular",
          price: "179.99"
        }, {
          id: "950390",
          title: "Machine",
          price: "179.99"
        }, {
          id: "793796",
          title: "Excel",
          price: "179.99"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" v-model="checked"></th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Course Title</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="course in courses" :key="course.id">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="inputs" :checked='checked'></td>
        <td>{{course.id}}</td>
        <td>{{course.title}}</td>
        <td>{{course.price}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```